# LWC datatable poor performance on large lists - virtual scroll

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am using LWC `datatable` component with `wrapText` set to `true` so my rows are of variable height.

I notice that when i have a large number of rows in my datatable (e.g. circa 10K) the performance is abysmal because datatable renders all rows in the shadow dom.

Is it possible to add virtual scroll capabilities to the LWC datatable (without re-inventing the wheel...)?

Comment: If anyone comes across this, there is a sample of how to do that here: https://github.com/skysan87/lwc-virtual-scroll-sample

I had to change it somewhat for my use and it is not very flexible but with enough perseverance you can make do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. There are no standard components that support faux or virtual scrolling, so you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: ...why am i not surprised...

Answer (score 0):

I've used https://tabulator.info/ which works well in lwc and has been very performant on large lists via virtual dom. Has tons of other features and is free!